# How can I generate a list of all passwords that apply to a specific rule?

Tags: password-cracking

So I'm looking for a way to generate a brute force password list that applies to a rule, for example:

> 3 letters + 3 numbers

How can I generate a list of every password that applies to that rule?

Comment: 3 downvotes a moment ago, but no comments? Is this too trivial or off-topic?

Comment: I have tried to move the question from being a software recommendation question to a more on-topic one.

Comment: @ilkkachu I don't see how it is about information security. This question is more about which tool and how to use it to generate a password dictionary.

Comment: @Xavier59, and password dictionaries can be used for cracking password databases, which seems pretty much security-related. (It can be done for a benign purpose or a malign one). But yeah, it would call for software recommendations (even more in the original form)

Comment: @ilkkachu Well, a computer can be use to generate password dictionaries and thus, to crack password. Could you tell me if I have to buy acer or asus ? I don't want to be mean, no offense, but if we follow your idea, nearly everything can be linked to information security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Crunch`.

It's a Linux tool, you can find it pre-installed on Kali Linux, check [this](http://tools.kali.org/password-attacks/crunch)
 link for more info.

For example, you can use the following syntax to generate your requested rule:

```
crunch 6 6 -t @@@%%% -o output.txt
```

the result will be saved in `output.txt` as the following:

```
aaa000
aaa001
aaa002
aaa003
aaa004
aaa005
aaa006
.
.
.
zzz992
zzz993
zzz994
zzz995
zzz996
zzz997
zzz998
zzz999
```

Be aware that using larger syntax will generate a huge sized files.